# Getting a LoadException when I put controller in nested FXML file

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, controller, fxml

The application works fine up until I put a fx:controller attribute inside of a nested fxml file.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Survey Creator");
        initRootLayout();
    }

    private void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            String pathToCss = "survey-generator/out/production/classes/css/Default.css";
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MyApplication.class.getResource("/view/MainLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(pathToCss);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

ClientController class:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;


public class ClientController {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> clientList;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        clientList = null;
    }

    public ClientController(ComboBox<String> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="475.0" prefWidth="923.0"
            fx:controller="com.surveycreator.controllers.MainController">
    <children>
        <fx:include source="MyText.fxml"/>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="668.0">
            <children>
                <fx:include source="ClientComboBox.fxml" fx:id="clientList"/>
                //more stuff below
```

ClientCombo.fxml - works fine until I add `"fx:controller="com.app.controllers.ClientController"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>

<ComboBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="519.0"
          promptText="Select Client"/>
```

After I add the above controller to ClientCombo.fxml I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/myusername/IdeaProjects/survey-generator/out/production/classes/view/ClientComboBox.fxml:7
/C:/Users/myusername/IdeaProjects/survey-generator/out/production/classes/view/MainLayout.fxml:18

    at com.app.MyApplication.initRootLayout(MyApplication.java:45)
    at com.app.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:28)
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. I think the info posted is incomplete: what is the name of the fxml file posted ?  Post the `MainController` it uses. Where is `ClientCombo.fxml` ? Where is it used ?

Comment: My apologies.. I'll fix that.

Comment: I believe that you are doing things wrong because I don't see any context management in your code. try using this tutorial
https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2017/09/18/using-spring-boot-with-javafx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your not managing fxml context in spring, bootifying should delegate this to spring so try using this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AirQualityFxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    private Parent rootNode;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AirQualityFxApplication.class);
        context = builder.run(getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]));

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        rootNode = loader.load();
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double width = visualBounds.getWidth();
        double height = visualBounds.getHeight();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode, width, height));
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: one advice: dont try to use the rest template I already did Why: the template should exist in a servlet context ( letsay a browser in a not complicated way ) so if your javafx application is not mean to be on browser don't loose time on it try using UniRest and you could manage your cookies or token by providing your http client.

may be there is a way to use RestTemplate (injecting a servlet context some how) but I don't have the slightest Idea how